# Headphones connecting to Xbox controller

Tags: controllers, xbox-one

I have an xbox controller with no 3.5mm headphone jack. I was wondering if I could buy those 3.5mm headphone jack to micro-USB cables and connect it to my Xbox controller? Kinda don't want to drop 50 bucks for an adapter, or buy a new controller.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No.
The audio connector attaches to the bottom of the controller, not the top micro-USB connector.  The official adaptors are pretty much same price as a reconditioned controller.  I can't find any reasonable hacks for adding a 3.5mm jack, without first butchering an adaptor.
As an alternative to the adaptor or replacement controller, look for an original headset, though they are flimsy looking.